# Rational solutions of $2(1+x^2)+4x(y-y^3)^2=z^2$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

Does there exist a non-trivial rational solution of $2(1+x^2)+4x(y-y^3)^2=z^2$.

This equation might seem very uninteresting to many of you but it has resulted after solving many simultaneous Diophantine systems. My answer depends upon this one.

Edit: I am expecting some parametric family of solutions.

Comment: $(x,y,z)=(7,1,10)$ works (by a simple search).

Comment: Good! Though I am expecting some parametric solution.

Comment: Then you should edit your post to ask for that.

Comment: Thanks!. Done!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking $y=5$ gives
$$ (x+ 120^2)^2 - 2 t^2 = 120^4 - 1 = 11^2 \cdot 7 \cdot 17 \cdot 14401 $$
so $x + 120^2 = \pm 11 w$ and $t = 11 v$ and
$$  w^2 - 2 v^2 =  7 \cdot 17 \cdot 14401 = 1713719$$

```
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$ date
Sun Jan 27 18:51:05 PST 2019
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$ ./Pell_Target_Fundamental
  Automorphism matrix:  
    3   4
    2   3
  Automorphism backwards:  
    3   -4
    -2   3

  3^2 - 2 2^2 = 1

 w^2 - 2 v^2 = 1713719 =  7 17 14401

Sun Jan 27 18:51:08 PST 2019

w:  1339  v:  199  SEED   KEEP +- 
w:  1381  v:  311  SEED   KEEP +- 
w:  1637  v:  695  SEED   KEEP +- 
w:  1763  v:  835  SEED   KEEP +- 
w:  1949  v:  1021  SEED   BACK ONE STEP  1763 ,  -835
w:  2131  v:  1189  SEED   BACK ONE STEP  1637 ,  -695
w:  2899  v:  1829  SEED   BACK ONE STEP  1381 ,  -311
w:  3221  v:  2081  SEED   BACK ONE STEP  1339 ,  -199
w:  4813  v:  3275
w:  5387  v:  3695
w:  7691  v:  5359
w:  8629  v:  6031
w:  9931  v:  6961
w:  11149  v:  7829
w:  16013  v:  11285
w:  17987  v:  12685
w:  27539  v:  19451
w:  30941  v:  21859
w:  44509  v:  31459
w:  50011  v:  35351
w:  57637  v:  40745
w:  64763  v:  45785
w:  93179  v:  65881
w:  104701  v:  74029
w:  160421  v:  113431
w:  180259  v:  127459
w:  259363  v:  183395
w:  291437  v:  206075
w:  335891  v:  237509
w:  377429  v:  266881
w:  543061  v:  384001
w:  610219  v:  431489
w:  934987  v:  661135
w:  1050613  v:  742895
w:  1511669  v:  1068911
w:  1698611  v:  1201099
w:  1957709  v:  1384309
w:  2199811  v:  1555501
w:  3165187  v:  2238125
w:  3556613  v:  2514905
w:  5449501  v:  3853379
w:  6123419  v:  4329911
w:  8810651  v:  6230071
w:  9900229  v:  7000519
w:  11410363  v:  8068345
w:  12821437  v:  9066125

Sun Jan 27 18:51:33 PST 2019

 w^2 - 2 v^2 = 1713719 =  7 17 14401

jagy@phobeusjunior:~$
```

Comment: I will work with what you have provided. I will be back.

Comment: @ersh after $5,$ the next few $y$ that work are $11,15,21.$ Also, $y=40$ works, so some even $y$ are possible.

Answer (score 2):

The positive $x$ for which both $x$ and $-x$ give a solution come in the sequence $x_0 = 1,$ $x_1 = 7,$ then
$$  x_{n+2} = 6 x_{n+1} - x_n. $$
I see, in these cases we have $y-y^3 = 0.$ This suggests trying to gather the other $x$ values by the value of $y$ that works. Hmmm.

Alright, I put $y=3$ and $y = 5$ as separate answers. There are plenty of $y$ that do not work at all. If $y=7,$ we find $y^3 - y = 336.$ This is bad, as $336^4 - 1 = 5 \cdot 17 \cdot 29 \cdot 67 \cdot 229 \cdot 337 $
cannopt be expressed as $w^2 - 2 v^2$ in integers.

```
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$ ./mse
 x: -1 y: -1 z: 2 =  2
 x: -1 y: 0 z: 2 =  2
 x: -1 y: 1 z: 2 =  2
 x: 1 y: -1 z: 2 =  2
 x: 1 y: 0 z: 2 =  2
 x: 1 y: 1 z: 2 =  2
 x: -7 y: -1 z: 10 =  2 5
 x: -7 y: 0 z: 10 =  2 5
 x: -7 y: 1 z: 10 =  2 5
 x: 7 y: -1 z: 10 =  2 5
 x: 7 y: 0 z: 10 =  2 5
 x: 7 y: 1 z: 10 =  2 5
 x: -41 y: -1 z: 58 =  2 29
 x: -41 y: 0 z: 58 =  2 29
 x: -41 y: 1 z: 58 =  2 29
 x: 41 y: -1 z: 58 =  2 29
 x: 41 y: 0 z: 58 =  2 29
 x: 41 y: 1 z: 58 =  2 29
 x: 89 y: 3 z: 470 =  2 5 47
 x: 119 y: 3 z: 550 =  2 5^2 11
 x: -239 y: -1 z: 338 =  2 13^2
 x: -239 y: 0 z: 338 =  2 13^2
 x: -239 y: 1 z: 338 =  2 13^2
 x: 239 y: -1 z: 338 =  2 13^2
 x: 239 y: 0 z: 338 =  2 13^2
 x: 239 y: 1 z: 338 =  2 13^2
 x: 329 y: 5 z: 4378 =  2 11 199
 x: 409 y: 3 z: 1130 =  2 5 113
 x: 479 y: 3 z: 1250 =  2 5^4
 x: 791 y: 5 z: 6842 =  2 11 311
 x: -1241 y: 3 z: 470 =  2 5 47
 x: -1271 y: 3 z: 550 =  2 5^2 11
 x: -1393 y: -1 z: 1970 =  2 5 197
 x: -1393 y: 0 z: 1970 =  2 5 197
 x: -1393 y: 1 z: 1970 =  2 5 197
 x: 1393 y: -1 z: 1970 =  2 5 197
 x: 1393 y: 0 z: 1970 =  2 5 197
 x: 1393 y: 1 z: 1970 =  2 5 197
 x: -1561 y: 3 z: 1130 =  2 5 113
 x: -1631 y: 3 z: 1250 =  2 5^4
 x: 2359 y: 3 z: 4070 =  2 5 11 37
 x: 2609 y: 3 z: 4430 =  2 5 443
 x: -3511 y: 3 z: 4070 =  2 5 11 37
 x: 3607 y: 5 z: 15290 =  2 5 11 139
 x: -3761 y: 3 z: 4430 =  2 5 443
 x: 4639 y: 3 z: 7330 =  2 5 733
 x: 4993 y: 5 z: 18370 =  2 5 11 167
 x: 5089 y: 3 z: 7970 =  2 5 797
 x: -5791 y: 3 z: 7330 =  2 5 733
 x: -6241 y: 3 z: 7970 =  2 5 797
 x: 7039 y: 5 z: 22462 =  2 11 1021
 x: -8119 y: -1 z: 11482 =  2 5741
 x: -8119 y: 0 z: 11482 =  2 5741
 x: -8119 y: 1 z: 11482 =  2 5741
 x: 8119 y: -1 z: 11482 =  2 5741
 x: 8119 y: 0 z: 11482 =  2 5741
 x: 8119 y: 1 z: 11482 =  2 5741
 x: 9041 y: 5 z: 26158 =  2 11 29 41
 x: 16369 y: 3 z: 23950 =  2 5^2 479
 x: 17489 y: 5 z: 40238 =  2 11 31 59
 x: -17521 y: 3 z: 23950 =  2 5^2 479
 x: 17839 y: 3 z: 26030 =  2 5 19 137
 x: -18991 y: 3 z: 26030 =  2 5 19 137
```

Answer (score 1):

Alright, that works pretty well. For example, when $y = 3,$ and taking $z = 2t,$ we wind up solving the Pell type
$$  (x+576)^2 - 2 t^2 = 577 \cdot 23 \cdot 5^2 $$
There are always details: both $x+576$ and $t$ must be divisible by $5,$ so that
$$ x+576 = 5 w, \; t = 5 v, \;  w^2 - 2 v^2 = 577 \cdot 23 = 13271 $$
For each $w$ in the output below, we get two $x$ values from $\pm w,$ namely $5w-576$ and $-5w-576.$ The degree two recursion for $x$ is a mess, but we get less trouble with $u,t$ and therefore $z.$ Still intricate.

```
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$ ./Pell_Target_Fundamental
  Automorphism matrix:  
    3   4
    2   3
  Automorphism backwards:  
    3   -4
    -2   3

  3^2 - 2 2^2 = 1

 w^2 - 2 v^2 = 13271 =  23 577

Sun Jan 27 18:25:45 PST 2019

w:  133  v:  47  SEED   KEEP +- 
w:  139  v:  55  SEED   KEEP +- 
w:  197  v:  113  SEED   BACK ONE STEP  139 ,  -55
w:  211  v:  125  SEED   BACK ONE STEP  133 ,  -47
w:  587  v:  407
w:  637  v:  443
w:  1043  v:  733
w:  1133  v:  797
w:  3389  v:  2395
w:  3683  v:  2603
w:  6061  v:  4285
w:  6587  v:  4657
w:  19747  v:  13963
w:  21461  v:  15175
w:  35323  v:  24977
w:  38389  v:  27145
w:  115093  v:  81383
w:  125083  v:  88447
w:  205877  v:  145577
w:  223747  v:  158213
w:  670811  v:  474335
w:  729037  v:  515507
w:  1199939  v:  848485
w:  1304093  v:  922133
w:  3909773  v:  2764627
w:  4249139  v:  3004595
w:  6993757  v:  4945333
w:  7600811  v:  5374585

Sun Jan 27 18:26:11 PST 2019

 w^2 - 2 v^2 = 13271 =  23 577

jagy@phobeusjunior:~$
```

Answer (score 1):

```
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$ ./mse
 x: 1883191 y: 40 z: 175564058 =  2 59 101 14731
 x: 15226951 y: 40 z: 499630198 =  2 607 411557
 x: 28177657 y: 40 z: 680201290 =  2 5 223 305023
 x: 35790119 y: 40 z: 766951382 =  2 383475691
 x: 61524257 y: 40 z: 1007136670 =  2 5 37 127 21433
 x: 72580159 y: 40 z: 1094624642 =  2 41 47 284023
```

---